# Symfony Unit Test mock 2 repositories

Tags: php, unit-testing, symfony, phpunit

I have 2 database calls in one method but from different repositories, with the first call it working fine, but with second call is throws error, that it expecting different repo.
Here is the test class:

**GeneratorTest:**

```
class GeneratorTest extends TestCase
{
   function testGenerate()
   {
       $currencyShortCode  = new CurrencyShortCode();
       $currencyShortCode->setCurrency('USD');
       $currencyShortCode->setCurrencyShort('US');

       $regulator =  new Countries();
       $regulator->setCountry('USA');
       $regulator->setCode('US');

       $currencyRepository = $this->createMock(CurrencyRepo::class);
       $currencyRepository->expects($this->any())
          ->method('getShortCode')
          ->willReturn($currencyShortCode);

       $regRepository = $this->createMock(RegulatorRepo::class);
       $regRepository->expects($this->any())
           ->method('getInitial')
           ->willReturn($regulator);

        $objectManager = $this->createMock(ManagerRegistry::class);

        $objectManager->expects($this->any())
           ->method('getManager')
           ->willReturn($objectManager);

       $objectManager->expects($this->any())
          ->method('getRepository')
          ->with(CurrencyShortCode::class)
          ->willReturn($currencyRepository);

       $objectManager->expects($this->any())
          ->method('getRepository')
          ->with(RegulatorCountries::class)
          ->willReturn($regRepository);

       $generator = new Generate($objectManager);
       $generator->generate();
    }
}
```

**Class generate:**

```
class Generate
 {
    private $repo;
 public function __construct(ManagerRegistry $managerRegistry)
   {
        $this->repo = $managerRegistry->getManager();
   }

 public function generate()
   {         
    $data= $this->repo->getRepository(CurrencyShortCode::class)->getShortCode();
    $data1 = $this->repo->getRepository(RegulatorCountries::class)->getInitial();

   }

 }
```

I suppose the issue is with this lines:

```
$objectManager->expects($this->any())
           ->method('getRepository')
            ->with(CurrencyShortCode::class)
           ->willReturn($currencyRepository);

        $objectManager->expects($this->any())
            ->method('getRepository')
            ->with(RegulatorCountries::class)
            ->willReturn($regRepository);
```

How to tell to test when first time call to the repository in `Generator` class use `CurrencyShortCode::class` repository  and for second call use `RegulatorCountries::class`, in my case for the second call it still uses the first repository  `CurrencyShortCode::class`. I tried to use `$this->at(0)`  but still not working. And if i remove `->with()` method it in the second call to repository the `$data1`  just null.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found Answer, I need to use `willReturnOnConsecutiveCalls()` method.
So

```
$objectManager->expects($this->any())
            ->method('getRepository')
            ->willReturnOnConsecutiveCalls($currencyRepository,$regRepository);
```